# Define page template in wp_insert_post

Tags: functions, page-template, wp-insert-post

How can I set which page template this page, created using `wp_insert_post`, uses? I want it to use `template-blog.php`

This is my current function;

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mytheme_admin_init' );
function mytheme_admin_init() {
if ( get_option( 'mytheme_installed' ) != true ) {
    $new_page = array(
        'slug' => 'blog',
        'title' => 'Blog',
        'content' => ""
    );
    $new_page_id = wp_insert_post( array(
        'post_title' => $new_page['title'],
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'post_name'  => $new_page['slug'],
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' => 'closed',
        'post_content' => $new_page['content'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'menu_order' => 0
    ));

    update_option( 'mytheme_installed', true );
}
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the [`wp_insert_post()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/), the `page_template` argument reads as follow:

> page_template: If post_type is ‘page’, will attempt to set the page
>   template. On failure, the function will return either a WP_Error or 0,
>   and stop before the final actions are called. If the post_type is not
>   ‘page’, the parameter is ignored. You can set the page template for a
>   non-page by calling update_post_meta() with a key of
>   ‘_wp_page_template’.

So, you need to insert the page using `wp_insert_post()` and assign the page template using the `page_template` argument:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mytheme_admin_init' );
function mytheme_admin_init() {
    if ( ! get_option( 'mytheme_installed' ) ) {
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title'     => 'Blog',
            'post_type'      => 'page',
            'post_name'      => 'blog',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status'    => 'closed',
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_author'    => get_user_by( 'id', 1 )->user_id,
            'menu_order'     => 0,
            // Assign page template
            'page_template'  => 'template-blog.php'
        ) );

        update_option( 'mytheme_installed', true );
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to set a "page template" for another post type:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'mytheme_admin_init' );
function mytheme_admin_init() {
    if ( ! get_option( 'mytheme_installed' ) ) {
        $new_page_id = wp_insert_post( array(
            'post_title'     => 'Blog',
            'post_type'      => 'my_custom_post_type',
            'post_name'      => 'blog',
            'comment_status' => 'closed',
            'ping_status'    => 'closed',
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post_author'    => get_user_by( 'id', 1 )->user_id,
            'menu_order'     => 0
        ) );

        if ( $new_page_id && ! is_wp_error( $new_page_id ) ){
            update_post_meta( $new_page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'template-blog.php' );
        }

        update_option( 'mytheme_installed', true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you link to that quote?

Comment: This answer is very old, I couldn't find the reference for that quote, but I've found that the answer was not totally correct. It was working fine but in case of page post type, the page template can be set directly using `wp_insert_post()`. See updated answer.

Comment: Since I had to debug the core to find out, I think it's also worth noting that the template parameter is relative to your theme folder. So in case you keep templates under a `/templates` subdirectory, you should pass `templates/template-blog.php` as template parameter.